# Interpreting input as hexadecimal numbers

Tags: c++, hex, ascii

I was having a bit of trouble trying to interpret my input as hexadecimal numbers. For example if given the input of `40A2`, and assuming I have an array at size 2<sup>16</sup>, how would I access the following example?

```
arr[0x40A2] //this is simply accessing the array at binary 0100 0000 1010 0010 
              which is at index 16546
```

I'm just having a bit of trouble with this because as the program receives input from the user, numbers come in interpreted as ASCII values, and need to be interpreted as hexadecimal values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ convert hex string to signed integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040681/how-to-read-hex-values-from-a-file-using-fstream-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you read the input? C++ standard input streams understand the [`std::hex` modifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex):

```
unsigned int index;
std::cin >> std::hex >> index;
```